# Possible to do "relative" Expires HTTP headers?

Tags: http, http-headers

For example, I want my static files to expire 7 days after they're first downloaded. What should I set the Expires header value to be?

Answer (score 3):

Just stumbled across this trying to find something else — but you shouldn’t be using Expires in this case. Use Cache-Control:

```
Cache-Control: public, max-age=604800
```

(604800 is 7 days in seconds).

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this server side. Generate the timestamp calculating the value, then send back the header with that value.

Example with PHP

```
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime("+7 days")));
```